# "However, Discipline Committee meetings, nor Discipline Appeal meetings...": is this grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

The parent requested a copy of the minutes from the Discipline Committee meeting.  However, Discipline Committee meetings, nor Discipline Appeal meetings, are formally recorded in any manner.

Comment: It's General Reference that "nor" in the second sentence requires "neither", which is missing.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Proofreading is off topic (please see the [FAQ]). You are welcome to recast as a question about English vocabulary or grammar. Thanks.

Comment: Please never just ask “Is this correct?”  It shows no effort on your part, and gives us nothing to go on.  As [the Help Center says in its “How to ask a good question” section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):  **“Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!”** Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The 2nd sentence is awkward at best.  Here's a smoother version:

***Neither the Discipline Committee meetings nor the Discipline Appeal meetings are formally recorded in any manner.***

Comment: No "at best" about it. I'm grammatically tolerant, but OP's sentence isn't "awkward" - it's simply ***wrong***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - or it can be restated as "Discipline Committee meetings ***and*** Discipline Appeal meetings are ***not*** formally recorded in any manner."

Comment: There must be various ways it can be *validly* rephrased, and doubtless some of those could be described as "awkward". But as it stands we're not dealing with a question that could really interest *linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts*, unless there's some reason why speakers of OP's native language have particular difficulty with constructions like *neither/nor*. In which case it would probably be Off Topic anyway, and should be on linguists.SE.

Comment: _Nor_ requires some preceding negative trigger. _Neither_ is the prototype, but any strong negative will do.

Comment: @JohnLawler has it exactly right. "Discipline Committee meetings are not formally recorded in any manner, nor are Discipline Appeal meetings" will work. But the *not* has to come before the *nor*.